# Bibliography - I can't see my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I try to include my bibliography bit after running my TeX file, but I can't see anything. What have I done wrong? The file Bibliography lies in the same folder as the TeX file.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=3.3cm, right=3.3cm, bottom=3cm, foot=0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[small]{titlesec}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\parskip1ex


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}


    \title{my title}
    \author{my name}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}


\vspace{3cm}
\begin{abstract}

blabla

\newpage



\setcounter{page}{1}
\onehalfspacing

\section{Introduction}

blabla


\section{Responsibility and the Market oder (!!!) The Ethical Potential of the Market}

blabla

\section{Conclusion}

blabla


\newpage
 %LITERATURVERZEICHNIS
\singlespacing

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Works Cited}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Works Cited}
\bibliographystyle{econometrica}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

FILE: Bibliography

```
% Bibliography for Hausarbeit

@ARTICLE{anderson1990,
    author="Anderson, Elizabeth",title="The Ethical Limitations of the Market",journal="Economics and Philosophy",volume="6",year="1990",pages="179-205"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you running BibTeX?

Comment: Is the file that contains the bibliographic entries named `Bibliography` (i.e., without an exension) or `Bibliography.bib`? BibTeX assumes that these files have extension `.bib`.